# How to detect the event of the power button being pressed

Tags: windows

Is there a way in windows to detect the event of pressing the physical power button, and after detecting the event execute or run a batch file. I basically
want to run a batch file that reboots the computer once the power button is pressed

Comment: You cannot detect a hard shutdown. There are events generated for a normal shutdown. See [Executing a batch script on Windows shutdown](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12434863)

Comment: Is there a way to track it being turned on? I had assumed that that was what the OP wanted.

Comment: @Xavierjazz, no OS is loaded at the time the power button is pressed to turn it on.  So if that was the meaning and the goal is to run something, it could be added to the startup sequence.

Comment: I want to run a batch file that reboots the computer once the power button is pressed

Comment: Then shouldn't that be your original question?

Comment: yes sorry just updated it

Comment: What version(s) of Windows does this question relate to?

Comment: Windows 10 for now

Answer (score -1):

You would need to know the [scan code (section Power Saving)](https://www.win.tue.nl/~aeb/linux/kbd/scancodes-1.html#ss1.9) for the power button key. Once you have this, then you could use software like AutoHotkey to overwrite the behavior of the buttons scancode to execute a command or batch file once the button is pressed.